# Does a solid-state DIN relay typically need a flyback diode when switching an inductive load?

Tags: solid-state-relay, flyback, din

I'm using this Phoenix Contact DIN rail relay, DigiKey part [277-17665-ND](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/phoenix-contact/2905657/277-17665-ND/9381938) ([data sheet](https://www.phoenixcontact.com/pxc-oc-itemdetail-pdf-web/eshop?lineItemType=LineItem&UID=2905657)). I thought it would be prudent to add a flyback diode, but looking at the data sheet, it vaguely suggests it already has protection.

In the section “Input Data”, there’s a line “Type of protection” with value “Free-wheeling diode.” In the section “Output Data,” “Type of protection” says “Reverse polarity protection” and “Surge protection.” Later it says the rated surge voltage is 4 kV.

I don’t know much about industrial controls, but it would be convenient if they could handle inductive kickback without external protection, so I wonder if they don’t.

My inductive load is a motion [brake](http://www.automation4less.com/store/proddetail.asp?prod=MPC034-24-0500) ([data sheet](http://www.file-vault.us/pdfs/NEMA34-0500_servobrake_A4L.pdf)) labeled 24 V, 0.41 A, 9.8 W (and that was borne out in measurement on the bench; the data sheet is incorrect).

Will my relay be okay without additional protection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think so. The diode has to go across the load so there would have to be another pin.

**You'll need to add an external diode across the load.**

Whatever that reference to "free wheeling diode" means, it is in the **input** section of the datasheet. There is also nothing shown in the schematic.

[image]

A 1N400x eg. 1N4004 etc. 1A diode is more than sufficient for this application.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions. It’s a bit awkward to set it up cleanly in my crowded cabinet, but I found a way to do it (and I happened to have a bunch of 1N4004 in a drawer).